# How to export a MongoDB database with numerous collections to JSON format using a single command

Tags: mongodb, collections

I want to export around 5000 MongoDB Collections to JSON format using a single command. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/smashew/6125915) script.

It's a bash script that basically does the following:

- Read the collections from MongoDB to a variable
- Iterate and call mongoexport for each collection