# How to use mongorestore to restore multiple collections?

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I want to replicate mongodb from staging environment to my local development environment, but it seems, that mongorestore only takes a single collection as it's input source. Are there any simple way to do replication of multiple collections without some bash voodoo?

Comment: Try taking a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27941897/how-to-export-a-mongodb-database-with-numerous-collections-to-json-format-using/27944416#27944416), as I believe the script provided handles importing as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there is no need for complicated script. You can just do:

```
mongorestore <dbname> --drop
```

in `/dump` directory to automatically restore all collections

Comment: CAUTION: if you are trying to ADD documents to a collection that already has documents and perhaps create new collections, this will drop all contents of each collection being restored that already has documents in it. "Before restoring the collections from the dumped backup, drops the collections from the target database. --drop does not drop collections that are not in the backup." https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#cmdoption--drop